# android find external folders through mnt

Tags: android

Let me get this out of the way; I am a beginner to java, I research the code I need and try to learn it while using it in my app.

I am currently stuck, not really sure how I can continue, ANY help is greatly appreciated.
I am trying to look in the /mnt/ folder for any folder with 'ext' or 'sd' in the file name. This is what I have so far, it gets me a null pointer exception but I don't know what variable is null.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    static File[] dirs;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        findMnt("/mnt/");
        AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("AppName").setMessage(dirs[0].getPath()).setNeutralButton("Close", null).show();
        AlertDialog builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("AppName").setMessage(dirs[1].getPath()).setNeutralButton("Close", null).show();
}
    public static void findMnt(String path) {
        File file = new File(path);
        if(file.exists()){
            File[] list = file.listFiles();
            for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
                if(list[i].isDirectory()) {
                    if(list[i].getPath().contains("sd") || list[i].getPath().contains("ext")){
                        for(int b=0; b<list.length; b++){
                            dirs[b] = new File(list[i].getPath());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is crude but will work for what I need it to. Searches for the sdcard folder, then searches for a folder with ext in the name, and if it fails it searches the sdcard folder for an ext folder.

```
String sd = findSd("/mnt/") + "/";
                String ext = findExt("/mnt/") + "/";

            if(ext == "ext not found"){
                ext = findExt(sd + "/");
            }


public static String findSd(String path){
    File file = new File(path);
    if(file.exists()){
        File[] list = file.listFiles();
        for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
            if(list[i].isDirectory()) {
                if(list[i].getPath().contains("sd")){
                    return list[i].getPath();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return "sd not found";
}

public static String findExt(String path){
    File file = new File(path);
    if(file.exists()){
        File[] list = file.listFiles();
        for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
            if(list[i].isDirectory()) {
                if(list[i].getPath().contains("ext") && list[i].getPath() != findSd("/mnt/")){
                    return list[i].getPath();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return "ext not found";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Memory Cases: if you take any new device or for ex. micromax funbook, then its having three memory

- /data/data/ (phone internal memory) getFilesDirectory()
- /mnt/sdcard/ (phone's internal sdcard)
  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
- /mnt/extsd/ (External sdcard) /mnt/extsd

You first need to be sure whether your External card is of `/mnt/sdcard/` or `/mnt/extSd` for that I have created a function

```
/**
     * @return Number of bytes available on external storage extSD
     */
    public long getExternalAvailableSpaceInBytes() {
        long availableSpace = -1L;
        try {
            StatFs stat = new StatFs("mnt/extsd");
            System.out.println("ExternalAvailableSpace Path : "+mStringExernalSD);
            availableSpace = (long) stat.getAvailableBlocks() * (long) stat.getBlockSize();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return availableSpace;
    }
```

if `getExternalAvailableSpaceInBytes()` returns `0` it means you need to consider `/mnt/sd`

To get all folders

```
ArrayList<File> mFiles= new ArrayList<File>();
    if(getExternalAvailableSpaceInBytes()>0)
             findMnt(mFiles, "/mnt/extsd");
    else
             findMnt(mFiles, "/mnt/sdcard");



public ArrayList<File> findMnt(ArrayList<File> files, File dir)
{

    if (!dir.isDirectory())
    {
        files.add(dir);
        return files;
    }

    for (File file : dir.listFiles())
        findMnt(files, file);
    return files;
}
```

Comment: This will not work will because I don't know the specific name of the folder, it could be anything but it will most likely contain sd or ext so I need to search for the folder without knowing the exact name.

Comment: I just solve your primary issue of taking Parent path and about listing you can see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040418/looking-for-an-explanation-to-get-a-list-of-all-text-files-that-on-my-android/10040459#10040459

Comment: That topic is not really related to the question.

Comment: @Demonicpenguin ok, updated for getting list of sub directory

Comment: The code is still kinda hairy, I am going to try and modify yours in the morning, but right now it is scanning two folders, but for each phone that this app goes on to may or may not have two folders, and the actual sd card slot name is different on each model.